# Is the computable numbers equal to the set of all the limits of finite length algebraic expressions?

Tags: computability, real-numbers

Let's call $C$ the set of computable real numbers and $L$ the set of all the (existing) limits of finite length algebraic expressions.

By $L$ I mean the set of all converging limits $\lim_{x_1 \to \infty} \lim_{x_2 \to \infty} \cdots \lim_{x_n \to \infty} f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and $f$ is a function that may be written as a finite length expression that includes only algebraic numbers, the variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and the folowing operators: $+,-,\cdot,\div,\sum$ and $\prod$.

It's obvious that $L \subseteq C$ because if a real number can be writen as a limit, it may be approximatted as much as desired.

So the question is: $C \subseteq L$ holds?, which may be rewritten as: is there a computable number which is not the limit of any finite length algebraic expression?

If it does exist, can anybody show me such $c\in C$ with $c\notin L$?

Comment: There are sequences of computable numbers that has non-computable supremum: see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Why isn't this obvious? Rational numbers are computable and every real number is the supremum of a sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: It seems that here the key fact is that the **sequence** is computable, but not the supremum.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Thanks for recalling the Specker sequence. It may not be an answer but gives me hope for the existence of such c. Matt Samuel is right, you should have written _computable sequences_ instead of _sequences of computable numbers_ in the first comment.

Comment: Yes, my comment was unclear. The kay fact is that a computable sequece of computable numbers can give uncomputable numbers. But  I'm not sure that any computable sequence is built by means of the standard operation cited in your answer, so I've not posted an answer.